# Make a constraint as 2 values in Pyomo

Tags: optimization, constraints, pyomo

I have an Obective function in Pyomo and I want to make a constraints for decision varibales.

Objective:  `model.round = Objective(expr = 2.2*model.x1 + 3.6*model.x2 + 1.1*model.x3 + 5.1*model.x4, sense=maximize)`
And I want a constraint to be a list of two values. For example:
`model.x1_cons = Constraint(expr = 2.2*model.x1 == [2 or 3])`
So I want `2.2*model.x1` to be either 2 or 3 and no values in between. But I cannot get how to make it in Pyomo as there is only equlity or inequality possible.

Comment: Start with an introductory text on Linear Programming.  You can't just code arbitrary make this = this or that equations.  There are many techniques to doing this, and I recommend you pick up a text on it and it will answer many questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the imports for the rest of your model, you can try the following:

```
from pyomo.environ import Var, Binary 

y = Var(domain=Binary)  # A binary variable

model.x1_cons = Constraint(expr = 2.2*model.x1 == 2+y)
```

if `y = 1`, then `Constraint == 3`. If `y=0`, then `Constraint == 2`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is not a pyomo issue, but a modeling issue. You need to use binary variables, i.e. a variable should be defined in {0,1}, not [0,1]. Once you have that, you have an option to use big-M relaxation, which would read like this.

```
-model.y*model.very_large_number <= 2.2*model.x1 - 2 <= model.y*model.very_large_number

-(1-model.y)*model.very_large_number <= 2.2*model.x1 - 3 <= (1-model.y)*model.very_large_number
```

As you can notice, depending on the value of your binary variable, the constraint can either equal to 2 or 3.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what your expression means. Is there any other simple way to define constraint as a range of 2 values?

Comment: Forgot to add, you should define `model.y = pyo.Var(within = pyo.Binary)`. Let's say your constraint is `f(x)`, and the binary variable is `y`. Additionally, have a "dummy" variable which is large enough, `M`. Then you need to write two constraints, which are complementary to each other. They would read `-y*M<= f(x)-2 <= y*M` and `-(1-y)*M<= f(x)-3 <= (1-y)*M`. Notice that when `y=0`, the first case will hold (for your case, constraint equals 2), and when `y=1', second case will hold (constraint equals 3). This is called disjunctive programming, and all other methods will be similar.

Comment: An alternative is, you can write the model with the right hand side equals to 2, and then equals to 3. Solve the problem twice and manually compare objective functions. The issue becomes if you have too many of these disjunctions, it might take a very long time to solve all possibilities one by one.

Comment: But how to define your constraint in Pyomo (code)? I mean using my names of varibales model.x1_cons = Constraint(expr = 2.2*model.x1 == [2 or 3]) ? How to integrate your condition in this line of code?

Comment: It should be split into four constraints. `model.x1_cons_a = Constraint(expr = 2.2*model.x1-2 <= model.y*M)` `model.x1_cons_b = Constraint(expr = -model.y*M <= 2.2*model.x1-2)` `model.x1_cons_c = Constraint(expr = 2.2*model.x1-3 <= (1-model.y)*M)` `model.x1_cons_d = Constraint(expr = -(1-model.y)*M <= 2.2*model.x1-3)`.

Comment: I don not know why, but solution is infeasible when I use these constraints

Comment: That could be because of many reasons. Don't forget to switch your solver to an mixed-integer solver such as  `glpk`, because your problem is not an LP anymore.

Comment: It is glpk of course. I just wonder that we cannot fix a constraint to 2 desired values as we do with inequalities in Pyomo. What's the difference for a model to find solution between inequality (between 2 and 3) and fixed (2 or 3)...Very strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246836/discussion-between-bburnak-and-roman-lents).